# Is the hookgrip dangerous?

Tags: grip

Are the chances of losing a thumb with hook grip really high? If not, can other problems occur, and which would be the most relevant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The hookgrip hurts, but it's not dangerous.

I'm not sure how you envision yourself losing a thumb. The roundness of the bar is far too dull to actually *cut* the thumb off.

If you're worried about the restriction of blood flow, this is also not a real threat.

In some orthopedic surgeries, tourniquets are applied to restrict bloodflow, to prevent bleeding during the surgery. A time limit of 1-3 hours is the rule of thumb, after which, the expectation of nerve damage or gangrene rises exponentially.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3421924/

So no, there is no need to worry about any long-lasting damage as a result of using hook grip, unless you plan to hold the bar for several hours straight.